# Matching an identifier except keywords

Tags: regex, perl

I need to find identifiers in a text file:

But I don't want a match if the identifier is a keyword. For example, if I have "for" as a keyword, in the following:

```
for (i=0 ; i< max ; i++)
```

I should get:

```
Found: i
Found: i
Found: max
Found: i
```

I looked into look-ahead assertion, but I wan't able to make it work:

```
$IDENTIFIER="(?!(for|while|do))[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
    while ($entireFile =~ /($IDENTIFIER)/g)
    {
          print "Found ($1)" . "\n"; 
    }
```

I get:

```
Found: or
Found: i
Found: i
Found: max
Found: i
```

This is not quiet what I want! I do understand why I get "or", but how can I make it smarter and exclude "for" entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need anchoring to make sure that you're matching an *entire* word (potential identifier). To a first approximation, `/\b(?!(?:for|while|do)\b)[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\b/` actually does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Even in Perl, clarity matter.  I recommend splitting the word-finding regular expression from the keyword filter to make the test easier to read, update, etc.  Also, if you want to filter out a lot of keywords, making a separate list is easier than cramming them into one regular expression.  Here is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $entireFile = "for (i=0 ; i< max ; i++)";
my @KEYWORDS = ('for', 'while', 'do');

while ($entireFile =~ /([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g)
{
    my $is_keyword = 0;
    for my $keyword (@KEYWORDS) 
    {
        if ($1 eq $keyword) 
        {
            $is_keyword = 1;
        }
    }
    if (not $is_keyword) 
    {
        print "Found ($1)" . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with some of the intent of this answer, but it would help if your code sample didn't have *dramatically* worse performance than the original. Either use a hash to test set membership (`$keywords{$_}++ for @KEWYWORDS` then `if (!$keywords{$1})`) or use a separate regex. Don't use a loop testing for `eq` that doesn't even bother to bail out early, and 12 lines of code for what could be done in between one and three.

Comment: Thank you hobbs!  I am learning here too.
Although your description is fairly clear, here is a full rewrite:
`my $entireFile = "for (i=0 ; i< max ; i++)";
my @keywords = ('for', 'while', 'do');
my %keyword_dict;
$keyword_dict{$_}++ for @keywords;

while ($entireFile =~ /([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g) 
{
    if (!$keyword_dict{$1}) 
    {
        print "Found ($1)\n";
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just look for something that looks like an identifier because you might be looking in a comment. You would only look for an identifier where an identifier could occur. An identifier cannot occur immediately after an "f". In other words, the real problem is that you're not anchoring problem.

You didn't show your problem, so we can't help you fix your problem. We can just answer your question blindly:

```
$ID_START = "[a-zA-Z_]";
$ID_CONT  = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]";
$IDENT    = "(?<!$ID_START)(?<!$ID_CONT)(?!(?:for|while|do)(?!$ID_CONT))$ID_START$ID_CONT+";
```

(This also fixes the problem that "done" wasn't treated the same as "do".)